# background and background-color is not working for default browser that comes with Redmi phones

Tags: html, css

Hi people I have been working on some website for my client. But this is the first time a client was also checking the responsiveness of my website in redmi default browser. Everything works fine but background colour is not working in some parts. I have attached images of chrome and default redmi browser.

[Redmi Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuorZ.png)

[Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tRqr.png)

I have tried both the codes (background and background-color):
first:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #111111ed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

second:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111111ed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace your color value with rgba and try

```
    background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.93);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.93);
```

Comment: @HAPPY SINGH you just rounded off my value ...no differ approach